# weakly_incrementable constraint while using iota_view

Tags: c++, c++20, clion, c++-concepts, std-ranges

To quickly create a for loop similar to python's `for i in range(100)`, I could do:

```cpp
for (auto const i : std::views::iota(0, 100))
{ /* ... */ }
```

However, CLion is warning me to add a `std::weakly_incrementable` constraint to my `auto`:

```cpp
for (std::weakly_incrementable auto const i : std::views::iota(0, 100))
{ /* ... */ }
```

I know that the starting value of `iota_view` must be `weakly_incrementable`, and I would assume that `auto i` will create an `i` that is the same type of the starting value.

But is it true? Is it possible for it to create something of a totally different type (not even weakly incrementable)? And can I safely ignore the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for it to create something of a totally different type
> (not even weakly incrementable)? And can I safely ignore the warning?

According to the synopsis of `iota_view` in [[range.iota.view]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.iota.view):

```
template<weakly_­incrementable W, semiregular Bound = unreachable_sentinel_t>
class iota_view : public view_interface<iota_view<W, Bound>> {
  //...
};
```

It is already constrained `W` must be `weakly_incrementable`. And since [`iota_view​::​iterator::operator*()`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/range.iota.iterator#4) returns the same type as `W`, you can ignore this warning.